# SWIFT 5 - AWS DynamoDB mapping enum

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

For now I am working with AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper

```
import AWSDynamoDB

class Assignment : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling{
    @objc var UUID:String?
    @objc var SK:String?
    @objc var Description:String?
    @objc var DueDate:String?

    static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "TableName"
    }

    static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "UUID"
    }

    static func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "SK"
    }
```

This works nice so far, but I want to add a custom Enum.

```
enum AssignmentStatus{
    case open
    case inProgress
    case closed
}
```

Is it possible to map this somehow?

```
class Assignment : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, AWSDynamoDBModeling{
        @objc var UUID:String?
        @objc var SK:String?
        @objc var Description:String?
        @objc var DueDate:String?
        @objc var Status:AssignmentStatus? //How?

    static func dynamoDBTableName() -> String {
        return "TableName"
    }

    static func hashKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "UUID"
    }

    static func rangeKeyAttribute() -> String {
        return "SK"
    }
```

I know I can map it with simple strings, but is there a more elegant way to solve this?